# Kotlin :How to remove item stored in Array in shared preference

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I want to remove an item (id = "productId") from an Array (key) stored in sharedPreferences. 
I write a Utility class that contains all these functions below, but the item still exist in the Array stored, how could i change my code to reach my goal.

```
       fun removeArrayDataByKeyValue(key: String, productId: String) {
    val prod = getDataInArrayList(key)
    val removeProduct = ProductData(
            id = productId)
    prod.remove(removeProduct)
    if (prod != null) {
        setDataInArrayList(prod, key)
    }
}
   fun setDataInArrayList(DataArrayList: ArrayList<ProductData>, key: String) {
        val jsonString = Gson().toJson(DataArrayList)
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, jsonString).apply()
    }

    fun getDataInArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<ProductData> {

        val emptyList = Gson().toJson(ArrayList<ProductData>())
        return Gson().fromJson(
                sharedPreferences.getString(key, emptyList),
                object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductData>>() {
                }.type
        )
    }
```

The following code in my activity :

```
   Utility(this).removeArrayDataByKeyValue("FavoritesProducts", productFavoris.id.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Removed from favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                buttonAddToFavorite.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"))
 finish()
                startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Your item isn't directly in your `SharedPreferences`. It's inside some JSON string in your `SharedPreferences`. You would need to `getDataInArrayList(key)`, remove the item with the matching `productId` from that returned `ArrayList`, then `setDataInArrayList(newList, key)` back into `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I think that what i did isn't ?

Comment: Nope, your middle step is wrong – `sharedPreferences.edit().remove(productId).apply()`. That's trying remove a key/value from `SharedPreferences`. You need to remove the item with matching `productId` from the `prod` list.

Comment: I change the fun in my code above, could you please tell me that's what should i do

Comment: Yeah, that very likely will not work. I'm still really new to Kotlin myself, but I think you can do something like `prod.removeAll { it.id == productId }`.

Comment: that's work, but how can i refresh the activity to get the new value of sharedPreferences or should i call it another time "var prod = Utility(this).getDataInArrayList("FavoritesProducts")"

Comment: it's ok now, thank you very much for your help 
i just added " finish() startActivity(intent)"  in my code above and the activity reloaded.

Comment: It's not the better approach to finish and reload the activity. See my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `ArrayList`'s `remove()` method checks for *equality* to find the object you want to remove. You should override `equals()` method in your `ProductData` class because if you don't, `equals()` default is to check for *identity* :

```
class A(val id: Int)

val a1 = A(1)
val a2 = A(1)

a1 == a2 // false, they are different objects
```

Even better, make `ProductData` a `data class` (which generates proper equals and hashCode methods).

```
data class A(val id: Int)

val a1 = A(1)
val a2 = A(1)

a1 == a2 // true
```

I'll give you some more suggestions:

- don't instantiate `Gson` each time: if you're always using the default configuration, reuse the instance. You can create a top-level property like `defaultGson = Gson()`. This applies to `emptyList` as well.
- avoid using directly `ArrayList` unless you have a good reason: use the more generic `List` and `MutableList`.
- remember to use lowercase names for arguments: `DataArrayList` should be `dataArrayList`
- if you want to listen to SharedPreference changes to update your Activity, you can use `sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`. A better approach would be to use a ViewModel with LiveData, but I assume you are still learning, so I'll leave this advanced topic for later :)